# Bean lost their object values when change the tab on tabview and refresh the page

Tags: jsf

i hope you can help me with that!!!

I can't offer deeper examples but i can try to explain or reproduce something similar on notepad to show you.

Imagine that i've a .xhtml page with tabview component and two tabs inside. When i press "F5" without change between these tabs my page works normally , but if i change the active tab and hit F5, the java bean on the backend get lost it values and can't get parameters from the JSF context.

Could you imagine something about it ?

OOOpps... i had almost forget to mention that my java bean belongs to the ViewScoped.

An example of the stackTrace  .:

```
javax.el.ELException: //C:/work/project/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/MyProject/beadep/dev_domain/webProject/report/financial/edition/financial_data.xhtml @23,68 value="#{financialDataBean.customerData.customerGroups}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    ...
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: would you please add error stack trace?

Comment: Sure! i've posted an example up there.

Comment: _"I can't offer deeper examples but i can try to explain or reproduce something similar on notepad to show you."_ Why not? That would have us to start guessing. Not something I want to spend my time on. In [ask] an [mcve] is required. An [mcve] most often not makes company secrets publically available. So please make one!  I did not downvote (yet) but please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: did you try to change it to `@RequestScoped` ?

Comment: Hi Spara! Why requestScoped ? imagine that my page must display data beyond the request time.

Comment: kukeltje i'm working at company, so... i'think i cannot post the code around the internet. I'll try to read the articles that you've posted and offer some examples to you.

Comment: Please try a [mcve], not 'some examples'. And please remember that your company trough you is trying to get free support, so your company is (or you are) sort of 'obliged' to put effort in the question. There are at least 3 reasons that might get this question closed. Not having an 'mcve' and being unclear and as it stands being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. Cheers